# What is the reason for size of a pointer to a 2d array being 8 on gcc 4.2.1?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc

Here is a c program

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
 int(*p)[3][4];
 printf("size of p= %d",sizeof(p));
 printf("size of *p= %d",sizeof(*p));
 return 0;
}
```

I can understand that size of (*p) should be the total size of the array i.e.48 bytes in this case.
But gcc version 4.2.1 gives the size of p = 8.
WHY?

Comment: As far as I know the size of a pointer is always 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine, since it stores a single address which is 8 bytes in size.

Comment: Are you really wondering why sizeof(**p**) is 8? Then @user2225104's answer is proper. if you are wondering why `sizeof(*p)` is 8 though, then you are not alone. Why do you not post a sample program run terminal output?

Comment: My answers are always proper and to the point. Only some lack the textual reading skills and vote them down ;)

Comment: On a side note, there are various x64 memory models. Different OS pick different models. While on x64 a pointer always has size of 64 bit, the memory model chosen by the OS determines the size of int and long. Also, it depends on the CPU, how many of the 64 address bits are actually being used.

Comment: @Samik thanks. I forgot that i was working on 64 bit system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the value of a pointer is an address, its value is not equal to what it is pointing to. Otherwise pointers would not be pointers they would just be regular variables and therefore useless.

If you have a 64 bit machine, which you do, the size of the pointer will always be 8 bytes.

Edit: if you are wondering why `sizeof(*p)` is `8`, it is because `*p` evaluates to the first (unless you increment it) element in the array of elements it is pointing to. so `*p` = `p[0]`, `*(p+n)` = `p[n]`, etc.

So `sizeof(*p)` always equals the size of the type `p` is pointing to.

Comment: Is this "*why sizeof(*p) is 8*" a typo?

Comment: Just to clearly state this: For the OP's source `sizeof *p` is not `8`.  `sizeof p` is `8`.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers store the address of the data to which it points. The size of the pointer variable is always 8.

sizeof(*p) = 48
sizeof(p) = sizeof(&(*p)) = 8

PS : 8 byte size is only in 64 bit systems. It is 4 bytes in 32 bit and 2 bytes in 16 bit systems.

Answer (score 0):

when you say declaration is `int(*p)[3][4]`, 
you actually mean declare `p` as pointer to array `3` of array `4` of `int` type. Here `p` is a pointer where the size of pointer is `8` on your 64 bit machine.

Ideally `sizeof(p) == 8` & `sizeof(*p) == 48`